# Make close button on Modal "sticky"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following page: it's basically a modal that opens and contains only iframes embeds.

For the website layout, I am using bootstrap 3. For the modal I am using [Hubspot](http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/) [Messenger](http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/docs/welcome/) which itself generates the close button.

As the vertical list of iframe embeds is very long, **I am trying to set the close button as fixed=sticky so that a user in the bottom of the modal does not have to scroll all the way to the top to close the modal**.

I tried many things, most related to adding position: fixed, but none worked.

```
//this does not work unfortunately=> check the jsfiddle below
.messenger-close  {
   position: fixed
}
```

I'm not sure it is related but I had to set, [following this advice](http://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios) here, because on iOS i was not able to scroll iver iframes (now it works fine thanks to this tweak).

```
.fullscreenmodal {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;  
}
```

Here are a jsfiddle I created for the sake of this question:

- jsfiddle with my code: https://jsfiddle.net/68uLkepy/
- fullscreen vision of the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/68uLkepy/embedded/result/

**The page on which we click to make the modal open**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadModal()">
  <span>click button</span>
</a>
      <script async="" defer="" src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
<script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- load some js scripts for embeds that follow -->
      <script async="" defer=""  src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
      <script async="" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <script>//fb
      (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script>
function loadModal() {  
      var msg;
      var modal_content = '<div id="social-embeds-list">\
        <center>\
          <div id="embeds-wrapper">\
              <div id="item1" class="embed-list-item"><iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BPodiIYgG3K/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="776" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); margin: 1px 1px 12px; max-width: 320px; width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: none; display: block; padding: 0px;"></iframe></div> \
              </div> \
              <div id="item1" class="embed-list-item"><iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BPodiIYgG3K/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="776" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); margin: 1px 1px 12px; max-width: 320px; width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: none; display: block; padding: 0px;"></iframe></div> \
              </div> \
              <div id="item1" class="embed-list-item"><iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BPodiIYgG3K/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="776" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); margin: 1px 1px 12px; max-width: 320px; width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: none; display: block; padding: 0px;"></iframe></div> \
              </div> \
              <div id="item1" class="embed-list-item"><iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BPodiIYgG3K/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="776" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); margin: 1px 1px 12px; max-width: 320px; width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: none; display: block; padding: 0px;"></iframe></div> \
              </div> \
              <div id="item1" class="embed-list-item"><iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-0" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BPodiIYgG3K/embed/captioned/?cr=1&amp;v=7" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" height="776" data-instgrm-payload-id="instagram-media-payload-0" scrolling="no" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 1px solid rgb(219, 219, 219); margin: 1px 1px 12px; max-width: 320px; width: calc(100% - 2px); border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: none; display: block; padding: 0px;"></iframe></div> \
              </div> \
</center> \
</div>';

      msg = Messenger().post({
        message:  modal_content,
        showCloseButton: true,
        hideAfter: false
      });

}
</script>
```

**Hubspot Messenger modal settings**

```
// Hubspot Messenger options
Messenger.options = {
  extraClasses: 'messenger-fixed messenger-on-bottom animated slideInUp fullScreenModal',
  theme: 'flat',
  maxMessages: 1
};
```

**the modal css**

```
// specific to fulscreen modals
.fullScreenModal {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  left: initial !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;// enable scrolling over iframes iOs 
}
ul.messenger.messenger-on-bottom.fullScreenModal {
  bottom: 0px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  left: initial !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;// enable scrolling over iframes iOs 
}

.messenger-close  {
   position: fixed
}
```

The modal content which is basically just a list of embeds, one after the other one in a vertical list** (containing an example of embeds=> note that it is only an example as they change programatically according to what has been defined in a sort of backoffice; the number of embeds can vary)

For more reading convenience, I chose to not include so many networks but just instagram. The problem remains the same.

Remember the current close button (×), I want to make "sticky" is generated by Hubspot Messenger. You can check on the jsFiddle with Chrome Dev tools the html and css generated by hubspot (the css can be manipulated/overriden if required).

Btw, I found this [codenpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMgeZw) where they manage to make it work but I don't manage to apply this to my case for unknown reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be as simple as the following:

```
ul.messenger-theme-flat .messenger-message .messenger-close{
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

I think your attempt didn't work due to lower [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

https://jsfiddle.net/tao879gq/

Comment: hi there must be something in my global code that is creating an issue because your jsfiddle works but my local app not. i'll search more deeply but will soon give you the points. thanks for your help

Comment: God i just spent 4 hours remving bit by bit chunks of my code to understand why yours was working and mine not... I edited my question: the reason is unbelieveable=> I added animate.css inside the jsfiddle  external resources and class=animated slideInUp" in the jsfiddle Javascript (on the Hubspot Messenger classes)to better simulate my actual app and it's not working anymore. So i know 100% it was due to this. but why ? have a guess?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with my animate.css and now the jsfiddle with your suggestion does not work...as was my real app:) => https://jsfiddle.net/tao879gq/8/

Comment: it was hard to beleieve this animate.css was the culprit. after all it's sth that impacts how the modal enter the screen...and looking at their library it's just some transforms...but look https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/issues/26 i might have same issue. while it's still written fixed, it is behaving as "absolute"